# How to make the server keep responding to requests until its process is killed by typing ctrl-c

Tags: c

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     char *result1 = "Ian G. Harris";
     char *result2 = "Joe Smith";
     char *result3 = "Jane Smith";

     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     printf("Address server started\n");
     while (strcmp(buffer, "+++\n") != 0)
     {
         bzero(buffer,256);
         n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
         if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
         if (strcmp(buffer, "harris@ics.uci.edu\n") == 0)
         {
             printf("%s\n", result1);
             n = write(newsockfd,"harris@ics.uci.edu",18);
             if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
         }
         else if(strcmp(buffer, "joe@cnn.com\n") == 0)
         {
             printf("%s\n", result2);
             n = write(newsockfd,"joe@cnn.com",18);
             if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
         }
         else if(strcmp(buffer, "jane@slashdot.org\n")==0)
         {
             printf("%s\n", result3);
             n = write(newsockfd,"jane@slashdot.org",18);
             if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
         }
     }
     return 0; 
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    while (strcmp(buffer, "+++\n") != 0)
    {
        printf("> ");
        bzero(buffer,256);
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0) 
             error("ERROR writing to socket");
        if (strcmp(buffer, "+++\n") == 0)
        {
             exit(0);
        }
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
        if (n < 0) 
              error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a server.c and a client.c and I need to make some changes to my server.c so that it never quits until I press ctrl-c. I put the client part just in case.

below is the correct format:

client

```
> harris@ics.uci.edu
Ian G. Harris
> joe@cnn.com
Joe Smith
>
```

server

```
Address server started
harris@ics.uci.edu
joe@cnn.com
```

the only problem I have here is that when I type "+++" in the client, both the client and server quit. The client should quit but the server should wait for another client and continue responding to requests and printing the associated email addresses until its process is killed externally by typing ctrl-c.

Can someone tell me how to fix it? specific examples would be better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're accept()ing only once. Make another loop.

Comment: In addition to what has been said, if you want to accept multiple clients simultaneously, you can use `poll()` or `select()` in uniprocess, or multiprocess using `fork()`, or multithreading using `pthread_create()`.

Comment: This is the second or even third time you post effectively the same question! That's not how this site works!

Answer (score -1):

Try loop with accept:

```
while(true)
{
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR on accept");
    printf("Accepted new connection\n");
    while (strcmp(buffer, "+++\n") != 0) { ... }
}
```

Please note that this cannot handle simultaneous connections, you need to use asynchronous IO for that which is more complex.